# C multithreading : Race condition scenarios

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, volatile

In the below code I'm just trying to see if I would be able to insert an element into an array , from each thread. It is working as expected. But then I wonder , under what circumstances there can be a race condition here. Do I really need volatile here, or semaphores? I tried removing semaphores and volatile keywords, still it works. I want to induce and see a race condition scenario as well here. On the same lines, Can I create a node from each thread and put all nodes into a linked list? These are all imaginary scenarios..!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "small_appl.h"

void * thread_func(void * arg);

int itr=0;
volatile int idx=0; //array index variable
sem_t sem1;
int arr_th[5];      //array where each thread will insert an element

int func_pointed(int a,int num_t)
{
    pthread_t arr_thr[num_t];
    int iter;
     //create threads
     for(iter=0;iter<num_t;iter++)
     {
        pthread_create(&arr_thr[iter],NULL,thread_func,(void *)a);
     }

     for (iter=0;iter<num_t;iter++)
     {
         pthread_join(arr_thr[iter],NULL);
     }
}

int main(void)
{
    int ip1=5,ip2=10,rev;

    rev=sem_init(&sem1,0,0);
    s_type dev_s={
                    .f_ptr=func_pointed,
                    .str="Diwakar",
                    .val=5
                 };

    //initialize semaphore to 1
    sem_post(&sem1);    

    func_aux(ip1,dev_s);

    for(rev=0;rev<5;rev++)
    {
    printf("array : %d    ",arr_th[rev]);
    }

}

void * thread_func(void * arg)
{
    sem_wait(&sem1);
    printf("Got sema\n");
    arr_th[idx]=itr;
    idx++; itr++;
    printf("Releasing sema\n");
    sem_post(&sem1);

    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: In C, `volatile` does not mean what you think it means. In particular, it's not the same as an atomic variable, or anything that does memory synchronisation.

Comment: Race condition is not easy to produce.volatile in C is just to tell compiler not to optimize for this variable, not for multi-thread purpose.

Comment: You don't "need" volatile *anywhere* in this code. you also don't "need" the semaphore, since all you're really using it for is a mutex anyway (which you *do* need if you throw out the semaphore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create or simulate a situation where a thread overlays the work done by another thread, then remove the semaphore and strategically place the sleep, as:

```
void * thread_func(void * arg)
{
    //sem_wait(&sem1);
    //printf("Got sema\n");
    arr_th[idx]=itr;
    // print arr_th[idx]
    sleep(5);     <<== gives the threads more of a chance to wipe-out each other
    // print arr_th[idx]
    idx++; itr++;
    //printf("Releasing sema\n");
    //sem_post(&sem1);

    sleep(5);
}
```

You can add some `printf` statements that explicitly highlight the problem.

`volatile` tells the compiler to not remove a variable that is not used or at least appears to be unused.

You can update a linked list from multiple threads, but you must serialize the critical section of the code that updates the links (next and/or prev) in the list.

In windows XP and above the CRT is thread safe, so each thread can issue `malloc()`, `printf` and the like without having to serialize the threads around those calls.

Comment: can you please provide me some hint for what does serializing the critical section means?

Comment: @DiwakarSharma, the basic idea is to only allow one thread to run a small sequence of its instructions at any one time.  Remember all the thread usually run the same code, but some parts of it can only allow one thread to execute it.  Search for Mutex or Semaphore and there are calls to system functions that do this.  However, if you understand the concept of a semaphore then you can code your own serialization.  To explain more requires a chapter, but learn about both the concept of a semaphore and how to implement with C code.

Answer (score 1):

volatile instructs the compiler that the variable can change at any time.  This means that every reference to the variable must result in a read from the memory (and not reuse a copy of the value in a register).

```
volatile int i;
if(i==0) return
if(i==1) ...
```

if the `volatile` keyword was not there, the compiler would likely read the variable to a register once and check it for 0 and 1.

If in your main program you wait for idx variable to be a certain value like this, you should make it `volatile`.

```
while(idx==10);
```

Volatile does NOT make it thread safe, that is a different issue.  In fact, because you protect that section of code, you do not expect idx to change from one read to the next, so you do not need volatile.

If you want to produce race conditions (detect section of code being split), I suggest setting up 2 values which you increment in 2 separate instructions, and do this in a continuous while loop (no sleeping! if you sleep you reduce the chances of the critical section being split).  In the main loop, continuously check to see if the values are equal (again, no sleeping).  If they are unequal, one of the 2 sections of code have been split.  Also have a look at the assembly to be sure the compiler hasn't optimized something.